# Google Cloud Speech to Text API not working on Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I've tried multiple things but the code just ain't working. I don't even know why. Can anyone understand what's happening here? Many thanks, for real.

```
import io
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import speech

client_file = 'key.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(client_file)
client = speech.SpeechClient(credentials=credentials)

audio_file = 'record.flac'
with io.open(audio_file, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
    audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding =speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
    sample_rate_hertz=48000,
    language_code='es_ES'
)

response = client.recognize(config=config,audio=audio)
for result in response.results:
    print(f"Transcript: {result.alternatives[0].transcript}")
```

With this code I get the following Visual Studio Code error:

```
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 78, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 audio_channel_count `1` in RecognitionConfig must either be unspecified or match the value in the FLAC header `2`.
```

I'm a newbie programmer by the way, so most likely the error is due to something very stupid, but thanks again if someone manages to find what's happening :)

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the audio_channel_count as 2 in the RecognitionConfig? (I'm surprised that omitting it entirely is failing, admittedly.)

Comment: Hey I just fixed the error, it tends out that I only had to add the line "audio_channel_count=2" in the recognitionConfig. Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: Hi Mario Serna León glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)